# INSERT and SELECT Statements for Different Tables Same Page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am creating a beer journal.  When I want to create a new journal entry, I am inserting a row in the journal table with the ID of the beer I am tasting.  The beers are stored in a separate table.  After I insert the row into the journal table, I want to select the beer from the beerData table so I can display it to the user as they are completing their entry.  My insertion works correctly, but I am not getting anything back for the beer name.  I have tried a couple of different things and neither work.

```
<?php 

if (isset( $_POST['newJournalEntry'] )) {

    //Define POST Variables
    $beerID = $_POST['id'];

    //Create Record in Beer Journal
    //SQL Query
    $query = "INSERT INTO journal (beerID)
                    VALUES (:beerID);
              SELECT beer FROM beerData 
                    WHERE id = :beerID;";

    //Prepare Query, Bind Parameters, Excute Query
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->bindParam(':beerID', $beerID);
    $STH->execute();

    $journal_id = $DBH->lastInsertId();


    while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['beer'];
        }

    } else {
echo "Test";
}
?>
```

2nd Try:

```
<?php 

if (isset( $_POST['newJournalEntry'] )) {

    //Define POST Variables
    $beerID = $_POST['id'];

    //Create Record in Beer Journal
    //SQL Query
    $query = "INSERT INTO journal (beerID)
                    VALUES (:beerID)";

    //Prepare Query, Bind Parameters, Execute Query
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->bindParam(':beerID', $beerID);
    $STH->execute();

    $journal_id = $DBH->lastInsertId();

    //SQL Query
    $query2 = "SELECT beer FROM beerData WHERE id = :beerID";

    //Prepare Query, Bind Parameters, Execute Query
    $STH2 = $DBH->prepare($query2);
    $STH2->bindParam(':beerID', $beerID);
    $STH2->execute();

    while($row = $STH2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['beer'];
        }

    } else {
echo "ELSE!!!";
}   
?>
```

Comment: Question #1: why not to make it in *two* queries?

Comment: I did with my second example.

Comment: Is $beerID set correctly with id-value you expected? (and the same question for $journal_id)

Comment: Yeah.  I'm not getting any actual error.  The result from the select query just isn't echoing.

Comment: try printing out the $beerID just before the bindParam to see if it is still holding a valid ID

Comment: how does the data for the beer get into table beerData, is there a trigger on journal table?

Comment: may i suggest that you start storing results into variables and then 'var_dump()' them in your code. That way you can easily see what is happening at each stage of the process. example: Don't echo $row['beer'], instead var_dump($row). same for $beerID. Also, use $allOk = $STH2->execute(); and var_dump($allOk). Ensure that PDO will throw exceptions on errors!

Comment: I got the two queries to work.  I'm not sure what happened because my code is the same as the second example above.  The only thing I can think of is that the old code was stuck in the browser session or cache or something.  Thanks for the replies, sorry it was something apparently not code related.

Comment: glad you sorted it out. :-)